# Spitting out a Index view using parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.MVC and trying to learn...

I have the following controller

```
    // get all authors
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var autores = autorRepository.FindAllAutores();

        return View("Index", autores);
    }

    // get authors by type
    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        var autores = autorRepository.FindAllAutoresPorTipo(id);

        return View("Index", autores);
    }
```

If I try `http://server/Autor/1` I get a 404 error. Why is that?

I even tried to create a specific method ListByType(int id) and the correspondent view, but that does not work too (URL: `http://server/Autor/ListByType/1`)

Any ideas?

**EDIT** Oh, the `http://server/Autor` works just fine. The method without parameters is spitting out my view correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your class is called AutorController, and assuming you have the default route configuration of

```
{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

You should be able to request

```
/Autor/Index/<anything>
```

However, you seem to be a bit confused on the action methods. You could combine your action methods like so:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
    var autores; // I know this wont compile - but without knowing what type FindAllAutoRes returns, I can't make a specific type for this example
    if(id.HasValue)
        autores = autorRepository.FindAllAutoresPorTipo(id);
    else
        autores = autorRepository.FindAllAutores();

    return View(autores); // Will automatically select the 'Index' View
}
```

MVC will select the first valid action method that corresponds to your route data - so if you request /Autor/Index/3, you will get the first action method, but since it has no parameters, the id route data is not bound to anything.

Comment: I tried this, but i still get 404 error. My Route config is the default, controler/action/id.

I'll keep digging. Thanks!